# SQL Server - Given a Set of Columns, finding missing combinations within the Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, set

I have the following Table.  What I want to get is the missing combinations of Student, Class, Book.  ***I have a query below that does it***, but I would like others to provide more efficient queries (ie possibly ones that use group by) to find the missing combos.

**SQL FIDDLE HERE** - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16e2b/3

```
 StudentBook Table
 +---------+---------+--------------+
 | Student |  Class  |     Book     |
 +---------+---------+--------------+
 | Albert  | Math    | AlgebraBook  |
 | Albert  | Math    | FractionBook |
 | Bridget | Math    | AlgebraBook  |
 | Bridget | Math    | FractionBook |
 | Charles | Math    | AlgebraBook  |
 | Charles | Math    | FractionBook |
 | Debbie  | English | NovelBook    |
 | Debbie  | English | PoemBook     |
 | Edward  | English | PoemBook     |
 | Frank   | English | PoemBook     |
 +---------+---------+--------------+
```

The following Rows in the Set are the missing combinations

```
 Correct Result of My Query Below
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Student |  Class  |   Book    |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
 | Edward  | English | NovelBook |
 | Frank   | English | NovelBook |
 +---------+---------+-----------+
```

And I can use the following Query to get the Missing Combinations, but I want a faster more efficient solutions. Basically I'm looking for ***other more Effective Techniques***, such as possibly using Group By.

```
WITH CTE_ClassBooks AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT Class, Book FROM StudentBook
),
CTE_StudentClasses AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT Student, Class FROM StudentBook
),
CTE_CombosOfStudentClassBooks AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT b.Student, a.Class, a.Book 
   FROM CTE_ClassBooks a 
   INNER JOIN CTE_StudentClasses b ON a.Class = B.Class
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_CombosOfStudentClassBooks
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM StudentBook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little faster, your route doesn't seem terribly inefficient though.

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT Class,Book FROM Table1)
SELECT b.Student,a.*
FROM cte a
JOIN Table1 b
    ON  a.Class = b.Class
LEFT JOIN Table1 c
    ON  a.Class = c.CLass
    AND a.Book = c.Book
    AND b.Student = c.Student
WHERE c.Class IS NULL
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d63bc/8/0)

Comment: Just missing a DISTINCT, but works and is 15% faster.  If I replace my EXCEPT with a LEFT JOIN of CTE_CombosOfStudentClassBooks with StudentBook Table it gives the same Query Plan.  Oddly, SQL Optimizer usings 2 table scans in the EXCEPT instead of doing something else behind the scenes, like a HASH JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S1.STUDENT,S1.CLASS,S2.BOOK FROM 
STUDENTBOOK S1,(SELECT DISTINCT CLASS,BOOK FROM STUDENTBOOK) S2
WHERE S1.CLASS = S2.CLASS
AND S1.BOOK <> S2.BOOK
EXCEPT
SELECT STUDENT,CLASS,BOOK FROM STUDENTBOOK
```

Comment: This uses 4 table scans, and it's hard to love an answer that uses old-style joins, but it does indeed get the requested results without a CTE.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your efforts.  But this only gives the "right" answer for this data set.  For example if I add "Charles, Math, CalcBook", it should tell me "Albert" and "Bridget" are missing.  But it doesn't.  Check out the SQL Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06cca/2